# How to redirect a domain alias to a subfolder of the primary domain using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to figure out how to redirect a domain alias [www.alias.com] to a subfolder [/subfolder/] of the primary domain [www.primary.com] so that the users still see the primary domain name:

i.e.

requests for: www.alias.com/whatever/

get redirected to: www.primary.com/subfolder/whatever/

-thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?alias\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.primary.com/subfolder/%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```